# Splunk returns some queries much faster than others

Tags: splunk

I am working with *access_combined_wcookie* data (essentially Nginx log files) in Splunk. An example of a record is below:

```
5/25/14 2:44:08.000 AM  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [25/May/2014:02:44:08 -0500] "GET /somepath/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9696 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"
```

I'm specifically interested in being able to run queries on the GET uri. So, that I can issue the following for instance:

```
/somepath/ | chart count by date_mday
```

I have not loaded over 60M records into Splunk and keep adding more each day.

I see that sometimes Splunk automatically indexes the "/somepath/" value and when I enter the query I get an immediate answer. But when enter the following query:

```
/some-path/ | chart count by date_mday
```

(essentially the same as above, but with a hyphen or dash), I have to wait a while for Splunk to generate the results. It seems that the outcome is volume-related: on smaller sets I get the result immediately, almost as if it were cached, where as the larger result sets take a long time (disproportionally so).

Is there any way for me to control that behavior? Is the smaller volume results get cached in memory and thus adding more RAM to the machine (VM in this case) would help get faster results?

Answer (score 1):

I have also posted this question to Splunk answers (an SO clone site for Splunk) and received a great reply [which I'm linking to here](http://answers.splunk.com/answers/137819/splunk-returns-some-queries-much-faster-than-others)

The gist is that a search term **some-path** is interpreted by Splunk as **some** *AND* **path**, so that's why the query takes so much longer. Instead, using the special search command [TERM()](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Search#Search_with_TERM.28.29) works a lot better.

```
TERM(somepath) | chart count by date_mday
```

Search can be refined further of course, as well. As a side note, a member pointed me to a field in this type of file called **uri_stem**, which actually speeds up the search even more.